# How can I detect non UTF-8 encoding in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I have a script like

```
a <- 1
# A very long comment, perhaps copy paste from somewhere containing the word ﬁt.
```

and I want to search for non UTF-8 encoding. How can I do this in RStudio?

Comment: non-UTF-8 encoding is literally all ASCII characters. you do realize that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realized, the answer is really simple: Just go to Edit => Find (Strg + F) and search for `[^\x00-\x7F]` + with enabled `Regex` field in the search bar.